# Being accepted then rejected to an academic conference

Tags: conference, paper-submission, presentation, interpersonal-issues, abstract

I submitted an abstract and received notification of acceptance to present at a conference.  The notification of acceptance asked for a short bio.  I provided the bio and was asked to provide more info in my bio relating to my academic and professional background. I provided the requested info touching on my experience in multiple disciplines in academia and industry.  I received notification today (10 days after receiving acceptance) that my submission has now been rejected.  They cited concern over the depth and breadth of the topic.

This hasn't happened with the many conferences I have submitted to.  I am not sure what to do handle this situation?  I have already devoted time and efforts to securing funding and completing the necessary studies to present.  Should I make attempts to rectify the situation and figure out why this was retroactively rejected?  Is this normal behavior for an academic conference?  Should I attempt to find out what happened in their review process?  What I can do to rectify the situation of having this submission retroactively rejected?

Comment: _Is this normal behavior for an academic conference?_ -- Certainly not in my field, but fields differ. What field is the conference in?

Comment: @JeffE The conference is on psychology and psychiatry.

Comment: May I suggest a paper on the topic of "The Psychology of Insincere Conference Invitations", in which the dishonored acceptance is exhibited as a figure, submitted to a journal whose readership significantly overlaps with potential attendees to said conference?

Comment: Just to be sure, you submitted only one abstract?  It is entirely possible to receive legitimate acceptance and rejection notices from the same conference, if they regard different proposed presentations.

Comment: Write a polite note asking if there has been some mistake, then write a less polite note to the organisers. Although I wonder if you have disclosed the full story. This sounds too crazy, even for people in the crazy business. ;-)

Comment: I submitted a single abstract and was in contact with the organizer, having an exchange of emails sent concerning the requested bio.  I provided the organizer with my current organizational affiliation but requested that it not be published in the program as I am moving to a new position.

Comment: Do you have a degree in psychology or psychiatry? Or any professional designation/license in those fields? If you don't, I wonder if they decided you're a 'dabbler' or not qualified.

Comment: @mkennedy My degree is in philosophy and CS.  I do work currently with a company in the healthcare field working on analyzing healthcare trends and working on predictive modeling for psychiatric illnesses.  The conference was also listed as interdisciplinary and has people in the medical filed, industry leaders and philosophers listed as invited speakers.

Comment: @mkennedy Do you mean a degree would be required to publish a paper?

Comment: @scaahu I'm speculating that an organizer thinks his qualifications aren't 'good enough.' But, like a scheduling mishap, we'll never know.

Answer (score 2):

I'm inclined to think the simplest answer is human error. Someone overbooked a set time slot and your acceptance was taken back. 
You'd be hard-pressed to get anyone to admit that, though. ;)